# Sorting the connected component in order

Tags: sorting, image-processing, bounding-box

I have a question in sort of connected component. I have a binary image ( onlye 0 and 1) I run the function from matlab:
f=

```
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0
1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
```

[L num]=bwlabel(f);

suppose that they give me the ma trix:

```
1   0   0   4   0   0   0   5   0   0
1   1   0   4   4   4   0   0   5   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   5   5
2   0   0   0   6   0   5   0   5   5
2   2   0   0   0   0   0   5   5   5
0   0   0   5   0   0   5   0   0   0
0   0   0   5   0   5   5   0   7   7
3   3   0   0   5   0   0   0   7   0
3   3   0   5   5   5   0   7   0   0
3   3   0   0   5   0   0   0   7   0
```

But you can see in this resul, the order of matrix is follow the column. Now I want to change this in to the oder rows, that mean number 4 is 2 , number 5 is 3... so on. 
The oder is left-> right and top -> down. How can I do that ( the oder of reading )??

Thank you so much

Comment: A simple solution would be to transverse your image before bwlabel and transverse it again afterwards. see answer

Comment: Are you trying to read text, as in the example images you posted? If so, please also post those images in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
f=f';
[L num]=bwlabel(f);
L=L';
```

does this solves your problem?

Comment: I'm sorry It doesn't solve my problem, because if I use this way with the image:   

![original image][1]


The firt - second - third connected component is:F -S -l like this figure:

![image 1][2]
It's wrong, because I want the order of 1-2-3-... is H - a - w-a -(point of I) - (point of I) - dash-i -i -s...

Thanks for your help, but It's not correct, do you have another way?


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nlZo7.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Rky.jpg

Comment: @user3607620 The answer is correct for the question you asked. The reason that `F` is labeled as the first component is because the `F` is the first component found on the first row of the image. Fixing this problem (making the `H` the first component found on the first row) is significantly different from the one you asked.

Comment: @user3607620 as refereed before the answer is correct for the presented question. what you showed on this comment is not the same as in the question and is not solved in the same way. if that were the images you wanted to label you should had presented them before. If you look carefully you will see that F is identified first because the first non-zero row belong to F as explained by beaker. I could give you an idea to solve it although if far more complicated and completely different from your problem an should not be placed here (note: the problem would be the points of I and dash)